# Open new browser window in Angular 6 using routing

Tags: angular, routes, angular6, electron, new-window

> I am trying to open a new browser window for Angular 6 SPA.

First of all, I tried to use `window.open(urlNavigate, 'Auth window', 'height=800,width=500')`

But It is redirecting to index.html despite of specifying url for the window.

Somewhere I found that using **electron module** can be used for the same.

**Ref:** https://github.com/maximegris/angular-electron/issues/58

Using that I am facing the below error:

[image]

I have tried a lot solutions to solve this error but I couldn't.

**"Is there any alternative option to open a new browser window in angular 6 using route ?"**

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
window.open("https://www.google.com", "_blank"); // Open new tab
window.open(document.URL, '_blank', 'location=yes,height=570,width=520,scrollbars=yes,status=yes'); // Open new window
```

Comment: I want new window, not new tab and that using routing not directly passing URL.

Comment: @GopalZadafiya Here are both methods for open new tab & open new window. 'using routing not directly passing URL' - not understand, what did you want to mean here?

Comment: It's angular application, So I just want to pass ("/sign-in/:email") kind of route and It should be redirected to SignIn component

Comment: Okay, for that use -  window.open(document.URL + '/sign-in/:email', '_blank', 'location=yes,height=570,width=520,scrollbars=yes,status=yes');

Comment: No idea about your routing URL, in my case it's working when I want to redirect '/dashboard' after login.  window.open('/dashboard', '_blank', 'location=yes,height=570,width=520,scrollbars=yes,status=yes');